# How to align vertically the content of this table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have this table:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \normalsize
    \caption{Elementos ideias e suas estampas na Formulação Nodal Modificada.}
    \label{tab:anm_estampas}
    \begin{center}
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l | c | l | c }
            \hline Elemento & Símbolo & Estampa & Equações  \\\hline
            Resistor                    &   \figresistor        &    \estamparesistor   &   \eqresistor     \\
            Fonte de Corrente           &   \figfontecorrentecc &       & \eqfontecorrentecc    \\
            Fonte de Tensão             &   \figfontetensaocc   &       & \eqfontetensaocc      \\
            Circuito Aberto             &   \figcircuitoaberto  &       & \eqcircuitoaberto     \\
            Curto                       &   \figcircuitofechado &       & \eqcurto              \\
            Amplificador Operacional    &   \figcircuitoampop   &       & \eqampop              \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \fonte{Figuras do Autor}
\end{table}
```

That generates this table below:

[image]

I'm trying to align vertically all the contents of all cells.

Answer (score 2):

You can define

```
 \def\vcent#1{$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$}
```

and then you can write `\vcent\figresistor`, `\vcent\estamparesistor`, `\vcent\eqresistor`, `\vcent\figfontecorrentecc` etc.